# Can't transfer large files via nfs

Tags: networking, debian, raspberry-pi, nfs, raspbian

When copying files to a mounted directory (nfs) it does so really fast in the beginning (>100 MB/s) but at around 1 gigabyte completed (using rsync) the speed drops until it stagnates at ~100 kB/s and often the transfer freezes completey. All the while my notebook becomes virtually unusable. (**edit:** *I'm probably interpreting this wrong. It slows down when rsync shows ~50% completed on a ~2GB file and ~15% on another ~6GB file.*) NFS seems to be eating up all ressources. Killing the copying process gives only *some* relieve and I have to do a hard shutdown.

I know that you need to tweek nfs quite a bit to get anything close to a perfect performance but this does not seem to be remotely normal. I have no idea where to start here.

#### Server side

I've got a raspberry pi with raspbian and there's a 1tb usb harddrive connected to it via a usb-hub. The pi is connected via ethernet cable to my router and is running a nfs server. The harddrive is formatted ext4.

`# /etc/exports
/share 192.168.188.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check)`

`# /etc/fstab
UUID=30dc34d3-878c-4ea3-8bcc-e817646f8ced   /share  ext4    defaults    0   0`

#### Client side

It's a quite good notebook running debian and it is connected to the homegroup via wireless connection.

`# /etc/fstab
192.168.188.26:/share /share/ nfs rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=14,intr`

Comment: I wonder what happens between 2 non pi systems when you try the same.

Comment: Have you tested the transfer with the laptop connected via a cable? I'm thinking the WIFI connection isn't up to scratch. Have come across many similar cases, especially with lower end wireless routers.

Comment: Well, 100 Megabyte/s isn’t happening with either Raspberry Pi or USB 2.0 hard disks. You should check what’s going on server-side as well as monitor actual network throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done an rpi-update?  The latest versions of the kernel now have NFS4 built into them so you should get better performance from them.